# Django's ManyToManyField column of model isn't showing in database

Tags: python, django

**I created two models in Django and used 'subcode' as ManyToManyField to create a relation between them.**

But after migration the column with ManyToManyField is missing in the database table.

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    Subject_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Subject_Code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Max_Marks = models.IntegerField()
    Course = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Branch = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Semester = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Subject_Code

class Marks(models.Model):
    roll = models.IntegerField()
    subcode = models.ManyToManyField(Subject,related_name='subjects',default=2)
    marks = models.IntegerField()
    sheet = models.FileField(upload_to='marksheet')
```

I checked the table for "Marks" model.
But it only has (id,roll,marks,sheet) and it is missing the 'subcode' column.

And now I cannot save 'subcode' using form because the 'subcode' column is missing in the table.
How to fix this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**: this is *expected* behavior.

A `ManyToManyField` is **not** stored as a column in a relational database. A many-to-many relation is defined as a *table*. Indeed, a table with two `ForeignKey`s, one to the "source" model (so `Marks`), and one to the "target" model (so `Subject`). This is a standard way to implement this, see for example the [Wikipedia article on *Many-to-many (data model)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)).

In fact Django makes a model itself for that. You can obtain this with:

```
Marks.subcode.through
```

In your database, this model will probably be named `appname_marks_subcode`.

For example if you look at this in MySQL, you will see:

```
mysql> desc appname_marks_subcode;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| marks_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| subject_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```